# how to render PNG with transparent background (Netrender) Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

i can't find any option like transparent output in Net/Network renderer

Answer (score 1):

Network renderer uses the parameters you set in the chosen engine.
If you select Cycles in Network renderer, then switch to Cycles, go to Film, check "Transparent" and select an output format that includes the alpha channel. Then go back to Network Renderer.